# Concatenate PHP inside of echo

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation

I've attempted to add an if/else statement within an already opened `echo` function, but page comes up blank. Not too sure if I am concatenating properly.

```
echo '<span class="year-tab-'.$x.' '.if ($single_year==$year_selected) { echo "" } else { echo "display-none" }.' ">';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can do this:

```
echo '<span class="year-tab-'.$x.' '.($single_year==$year_selected ? "" : "display-none").' ">';
```

See Ternary Operator on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have control structures inside concatenation

```
$style = ($single_year==$year_selected) ? '' : "display-none";
echo '<span class="year-tab-'.$x.' '.$style.'">';
```

That concatenation is a bit messy. `printf()` *might* be a bit cleaner

```
printf('<span class="year-tab-%s %s">', 
    %x,
    ($single_year==$year_selected) ? '' : "display-none"
);
```

Comment: Actually, you can use ternary operator inside echo's, there's no need to use another variable in your first example (for readability would be better to use an if though)

Answer (score 0):

Using the ternary operator:

```
echo '<span class="year-tab-'.$x;
echo ($single_year==$year_selected)? '>' : ' style="display:none">';
```

Note that for display value, you have to enclose it inside the display tag.